# Strip an entire block of html based on class or id with php

Tags: php

I have the following php function which is supposed to remove a block of html tag based on a given classname or id. I got this function at http://www.katcode.com/php-html-parsing-extracting-and-removing-html-tag-of-specific-class-from-string/

This function works as it should but seems to have problems when we have nested tags. In the example below i'm trying to remove the entire div block that has class 'two'.

This function seems to have problems with nested tags. It's not removing the div block properly. It's having problems figuring out beginning and end of the block. How can i rework this function remove an entire tag regardless of how many nested elements it contains. I'm open to other php suggestions. I can easily do this with jQuery, but i'm looking for a php server side solution.

**html looks like this**

```
<div class="test">
    <div>testing1</div>
    <div class="two">
        <div>testing3</div>
        <div>testing3</div>
    </div>
    <div>testing3</div>
    <div>testing4</div>
</div>
```

**php**

```
<?php
    $x = '<div class="test"><div>testing1</div><div class="two"><div>testing3</div><div>testing3</div></div><div>testing3</div><div>testing4</div></div>';

    function removeTag($str,$id,$start_tag,$end_tag){
        while(($pos_srch = strpos($str,$id))!==false){
            $beg = substr($str,0,$pos_srch);
            $pos_start_tag = strrpos($beg,$start_tag);
            $beg = substr($beg,0,$pos_start_tag);
            $end = substr($str,$pos_srch);
            $end_tag_len = strlen($end_tag);
            $pos_end_tag = strpos($end,$end_tag);
            $end = substr($end,$pos_end_tag+$end_tag_len);
            $str = $beg.$end;
        }
        return $str;
    }

    echo removeTag($x,'two','<div','/div>');
?>
```

Comment: I'm not answering well enough to put it as an "answer", but I'll point you in a direction. I've see people accomplish things like this with DOM and Xpath.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help me.

Comment: Using a parser is the only correct way to parse HTML ... not regex, not string functions. This is why you're having trouble. Like @TecBrat said, you need to use `DOM`. Try to make it work with that and post a new (or updated) question if you have problems.

Comment: This function only parses out simple non-nested tags. Parses to the first end delimiter it finds. Rather poorly written I must say.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but try something like:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($x);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = "//div[contains(@class, 'two')]";
$oldnodes = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($oldnodes as $node) {
    $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    while($node->childNodes->length > 0) {
        $fragment->appendChild($node->childNodes->item(0));
    }
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $node);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Did you test this. It's not stripping out anything.

Comment: @Pinkie you should be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score -1):

html should probably never be parsed with php that way.

use phps domdocument class to open the html as an object. you can then use domdocument methods to search the document for the block you are looking for (xpath), loop through the xpath results and remove them, and then resave the document in text form.

Comment: I think your Shift key is broken.

Comment: @rdlowrey iphone actually. who wants to use shift on an iphone.